# pooling equilibrium

Tags: risk, risk-management, credit-risk, entropy-pooling

I was hoping for some help on how to answer a question about pooling equilibrium. Suppose a bank wants to give loans of 1 million dollars to people, but it cannot differentiate between high risk borrowers and low risk borrowers. The high risk borrowers make up 15% of the population and have a default rate of 25% and would be willing to pay a max interest rate of 30%. The low risk borrowers make up 85% of the population and have a default rate of 10%, and would be willing to pay a max interest rate of 13.5%. In this scenario, would the bank be willing to pool together the risk, and if so what interest should it charge on the loans ? Thank you

Comment: Have you tried to calculate the expected value of taking on all the risks?

Comment: I took the expected loss : E(L) = 0.15(1 000 000 x 0.25) + 0.85(1 000 000 x 0.10) = 122 500. Then I took 122 500 / (1 000 000 - 122 500) = 0.1369 to see how much interest must be charged to cover potential losses. I got 13.69% for the interest that must be charged. This is higher than the max of 13.5% for the low risk group, so a pooling equilibrium is not possible. I am looking for help on whether the logic of this makes sense, and if not, then some help on what is the correct way.

Answer (score 1):

I'd argue as follows. Let there be two borrower groups, $l$ow risks and $h$igh risks. The population fractions are $w_l$ for the low risks and $1-w_l$ for the high risks. Their default probabilities are $l$ and $h$, respectively. No recovery. Their reservation interest rates are $r_l$ and $r_h$. We assume one bank (no competition), so any interest rate at or below $r_l$ will attract both, high and low risk debtors, at fractions equal to their population share. The total notional to be invested is irrelevant. We do not consider cost of capital etc.

From the institution’s perspective, an offered rate $r$ will pool the borrowers if $r\leq r_l$ and it will be beneficial if the bank's expected profit $\pi$ is positive (or at least not negative)

$$
\begin{align}
0\stackrel{!}{\leq} \pi & \equiv -1+w_l \left[0\times l + (1+r)(1-l)\right] + (1-w_l)\left[0\times h + (1+r)(1-h)\right]\\
&=-1+(1+r)\left[w_l (1-l) + (1-w_l) (1-h)\right]\\
\Rightarrow\quad r&\geq \frac{1}{w_l (1-l) + (1-w_l) (1-h)}-1
\end{align}
$$

which, in your case, equals 13.96% (NB: not 13.69% as in your comment). This rate will not be accepted by the low risks.

Does that make sense?

---

NB: The bad risk group does not accept a rate that can sustain its own PD. That seems odd ;-)

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation, its very helpful. For your NB, I do not remember exactly what rate the bad risk group would accept, but I do remember it was high, so I may have been mistaken when saying 30%. It was probably higher. Thanks again for your explanation.